# Sum of any cell in given range matching complex condition

Tags: excel, sum, range, conditional-statements

I was given a set of data containing airline tax data on coupon level and had to split the interlinable taxes from the YQ and make the conversions to EUR and USD. After ~ 1100 lines of VBA to get the report done as required, I've to make the sums and I'm done.

Basically, the tax data ressembles what you see in the screenshot @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6KGI.jpg but on much larger scale.
I need to take each possible tax code out of the data and make the sums and that's where I'm stuck. If the data was ordered in columns, tax code by tax code it wouldn't have been much of a problem, but as it's something that isn't required at all and would create a lot more columns when a coupon doesn't have a certain tax:

```
YQ BE IT HB EX MJ VT
YQ BE DE RA
```

Would become:

```
YQ BE IT HB EX MJ VT
YQ BE                DE RA
```

The first more compact view was preferred.

Anyway, how do I make the sum for each type of tax depending on the currency?
As far as I understand, it's a sum based on two conditions:
For any cell in the range:

Make the **sum of any cell** in the range A2:L12 machting the condition: 
"A_CELL.OFFSET(0,-1) = [tax code] AND THAT_SAME_CELL.OFFSET(0,1) = [currency]"

Could someone help me on the way to get this done?

Thank you in advance.
Cheers!

Update: VBA function used to get to result needed:

```
Function SumOf(taxStr As String, curStr As String, wrkRange As Range) As Double
Dim taxSum As Double
Dim rngCell As Range

On Error GoTo SumOfError

taxSum = 0

'Set wrkRange = rangStr

For Each rngCell In wrkRange

            If rngCell.Column > 1 And rngCell.Offset.Column < wrkRange.Columns.Count - 1 Then

        If (rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = taxStr) And (rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = curStr) Then
            taxSum = taxSum + Val(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    End If

Next rngCell

SumOf = taxSum

Exit Function
```

SumOfError:
    SumOf = 0
End Function

Comment: Don't get the whole picture, but usally this would be a task for `SUMIFS`

Comment: To get things running, I wrote a VBA function which does what I need (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your VBA does the trick.

However, using VBA is always a big buy-in of problems. So here is my solution using a formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B$12,A$2:A$12,$A15,C$2:C$12,B$14)
```

This is for the cell B15 of your example screenshot. You can paste it down.

If you want to paste it to the right, you need to adapt it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Jook. However it seems to return 0 (Office 2012 Preview)

I haven't concentrated much more on an excel formula as the deadline I was given is tomorrow at noon, so the VBA will have to do the trick for now ;)

But I'm gonna look for it anyway, because it's bothering me I can't find a formula which has the same effect

Comment: @AkiraTakizawa - meh, I made a little error - it hast to be B$14 not B$13 - corrected it.